# Error while handling chainer.function.max_pooling_2d in python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, chainer, max-pooling

I am using max_pooling function using chainer for maxpooling operation in CNN.

I am getting the following error. i have placed the code which i used for max_pooling operation.what i need to do to resolve this issue?

```
Pool_1=F.max_pooling_2d(Feature_map1_pool, ksize=3, stride=None, pad=0, cover_all=True, return_indices=False)
```

```
InvalidType:  Invalid operation is performed in: MaxPooling2D
(Forward)

Expect: in_types[0].dtype.kind == f

Actual: O != f
```

Comment: Please see https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tips.html#how-do-i-fix-invalidtype-error and confirm if the input data type is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InvalidType: Invalid operation is performed in: MaxPooling2D (Forward)

Expect: in_types[0].dtype.kind == f

Actual: O != f
```

This error indicates that the argument `Feature_map1_pool` has the dtype `'O'` = `'object'`.

There should be some mistake in creation of the array `Feature_map1_pool`.
There are many ways from which such array may result. The following code is just one example.

```
Feature_map1_pool = numpy.asarray([numpy.array([2, 2]), numpy.array([1])])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually i forgot to apply relu function before pooling. i rectified the mistake.